# монтирование HDD ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, hdd

Как смонтировать жесткий диск к установленной системе что бы место с нового диска распределялось под коревой каталог или каталог home ?

Comment: Перенести нужный раздел со старого диска на этот диск, например

Comment: Нельзя разделить одну точку монтирования на несколько разделов. Нужны либо дополнительные точки монтирования, либо перенос+слияние разделов...